# How to compare two tables in the same database in MySQL without having a foreign key relationship

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with word lists, in table1 I have two columns viz. sno and words; and table2 has three columns viz. sno, wordlist1 and wordlist2. There is no foreign key relationship between two tables.

Now the words in table1 can be present in either wordlist1 or wordlist2 of table2 as a complete word or a sub-string.

## Table1

sno words
1 peter
2 ravi
3 sham
4 albert
5 tom
6 mick
7 paul
8 simon

## Table2

sno wordlist1 wordlist2
1 adam fulton
2 ajay aravi
3 simon hasan
4 albert siddle
5 tommy harris
6 peter cook

I want a list of words from table1 that are not present in table2 in any form viz. as the exact word or as a sub-string.

Comment: I used the following query to get the matches and it works fine but when I add a 'not like' in place of 'like', it returns all the table values
<br>
select distinct t2.*
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t2.wordlist1
like concat('%',(t1.word),'%')
or t2.wordlist2
like concat('%',(t1.word),'%');

Answer (score 1):

The existence of a foreign key constraint wouldn't change the query.

One option is to use an anti-join pattern:

```
SELECT t1.sno
     , t1.words
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.wordlist1 LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.words,'%')
    OR t2.wordlist2 LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.words,'%')
 WHERE t2.sno IS NULL
```

Another option is to use a NOT EXISTS predicate with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.sno
     , t1.words
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM table2 t2 
          WHERE t2.wordlist1 LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.words,'%')
             OR t2.wordlist2 LIKE CONCAT('%',t1.words,'%')
       )
```

Comment: Thanks spencer7593 both the option work fine; but can you tell why 'not like' didn't work in my query where 'like' worked fine

Comment: @user3578365: A query with a `t1.words NOT LIKE CONCAT('%',t2.wordlist1,'%')` predicate will look for individual rows in t2 that satisfy the condition. For example, "peter" matches a row in t2, but the predicate is going to return true for five other rows in t2, so five copies of "peter" are going to be returned.